# Flexible database design for an inventory system

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I have to build an inventory management system for my school and this is the problem that I'm facing:

There are multiple types of equipment that I have to store in my system:

> Computers, Printers, Cartridges, Projectors, Mouses, Keyboards etc.

And there is some common data about each item, regardless it's type:

> TEMSID (like a barcode), SerialNumber, PurchaseDate, RegisterDate and other, see item entity for more.

Also, each item type has it's specific fields that have to be stored.

This is how I am going to deal with it, however I'm not sure about it:

1. [item] table stores common data
2. [item] table has one to one relationships with other tables which store more details about specific items.
3. Repetitive data (Manufacturer, Model, Resolution etc.) is stored in other tables [itemType] to reduce redundancy.

[image: This is the schema]
*Ignore those FK IDs from item table*

---

I fell like it is a bad design.

If there is another more efficient solution, I'm ready to start designing from scratch.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask yourself: what happens, if the school gets an item, for which you don't have any table (f.e. like `Printer` and `PrinterType`) in your database? And if this can happen often? Then you have to add new tables to the database each time.

On the other hand, you have type specific properties, but yet they can be common, like `model` or `color`.

If I were you, I would make a dynamic system, which means, the administrator/user can add any item (device) type and can add any properties to it.

I would design the db like this:

[image]

We have device types like printer, projector, etc. Then we have our `devices` table with the basic data and connected to the `devicetypes` table. Then we have a `properties` table, in which we hold the other properties of all the device types (one property only once, no redundancy). And finally, we have a `propvalues` table, where we store the different property values of each device.

F. e. in the above example, the device with `id: 1` has two properties (model and color) with the values `hp` and `true`.

With this design, the user/administrator can manage as many properties as many he want.

One special thing: the `value` field should be f. e. a `string` field, because it can hold values like numbers, string, dates, etc. And in the view you have to cast this value depending on the `datatype`.

And if you have to manage compatibility data too, of course you can do it more generic. But maybe this should be a homework :-)

Comment: But there is something more that I haven't included in the screenshot. The system stores information about Computers too, and a computer is a collection of other items from db (I mean Computer = CPU + PSU + Motherboard + GPU + StorageDevice + ... ). Which approach to use? To add a new column - parentID in device table (where parentID will be the computer's ID for CPU, PSU records) or to keep this state and to add another table - ComponentParts with 2 columns: DeviceID, PartID?

Comment: Altough it can work with parentID, but in this case we will have records in the device table, where parentID will be null, which is less perfect. And on the other hand components are for me a new entity, thus I would go the other way and hold the data in a separate table. Fun fact: Baba means in Hungarian a little baby.

Comment: I came here to thank you for this amazing solution! I've designed my system the way you said and it's perfect!

Comment: I'm glad to hear that.